# How to use DateRangePicker with foreach loop to filter dates?

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with implementing daterangepicker with foreach loop to use it as a filter (by dates). So I have data coming from db into table. There is a foreach loop to iterate the data into td tags. I have a script which works with 'static' table as in without foreach loop (just some td tags with test data). But it does not want to work with foreach loop. Some code:

```
<div id="daterange" class="btn btn-success btn-lg datepick">
                <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <br>
            <table id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Worker</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<c:forEach var="app" items="${listAppointments}">
                            <tr>

                                <td>${app.service.name}</td>
                                <td>${app.service.price} </td>
                                <td><fmt:formatDate value="${app.userdate}" pattern="dd-MM-YYYY" /></td>
<td><fmt:formatDate value="${app.userdate}" pattern="HH:mm" /></td>

                                <td><a tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Client" data-html="true" data-content="Name: <b>${app.user.name} ${app.user.surname}</b> <br><br> Phone: <b>${app.user.phone}</b><br><br> Email: <b>${app.user.email}</b>">${app.user.name} ${app.user.surname}</a></td>     

                                <td><a tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Worker" data-html="true" data-content="Name: <b>${app.worker.name} ${app.worker.surname}</b> <br><br> Phone: <b>${app.worker.phone}</b><br><br> Email: <b>${app.worker.email}</b>">${app.worker.name} ${app.worker.surname}</a></td>     
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        var start = moment("2017-01-01 12:34:16");
        var end = moment("2018-03-03 10:08:07");

        function cb(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange3 span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        }

        $('#daterange').daterangepicker({

            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,

            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            },

            "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
        }, cb);

        cb(start, end);

    });


    $('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        var start = picker.startDate;
        var end = picker.endDate;

        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var min = start;
                    var max = end;
                    var startDate = new Date(data[2]);

                    if (min == null && max == null) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
        );
        table.draw();
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    });
    $('#daterange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        start = end = null;
        $(this).val('');
        table.draw();
    });
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    });
});
```

So I tried to change the picker from id to class, but it is still the same.

What it does is: the table is displaying the data fine, then after I choose some dates(does not matter what dates) with datepicker - all the rows from the table disappear, and when I press cancel, they appear again.

What I need it to do is to display table rows with dates being in sort of between of 'from' and 'to' - from the datepicker filering.